# Logstash replace colon with arrow

Tags: json, ruby, csv, logstash, amazon-kinesis

My goal is to read data from kinesis and upload csv file on s3, but in csv file arrow(=>) is coming in json data insted of colon(:)

Logstash config file

```
input {
  kinesis {
    application_name => "logstash"
    kinesis_stream_name => "events"
    type => "kinesis"
    region => "us-east-1"
    profile => "default"
    metrics => "cloudwatch"
    codec => "json"
  }
}

filter {
    grok {
      match => { "[data][ti]" => "%{YEAR:event_year}-%{MONTHNUM2:event_month}-%{MONTHDAY:event_day}" }
   }
}

output {
  s3 {
    bucket => "test-logstash"
    region => "us-east-1"
    prefix => "%{event_year}/%{event_month}/%{event_day}/%{[data][brandid]}/%{[data][event_name]}"
    encoding => "none"
    codec => csv {
        separator => "␁"
    }
    size_file => 200000000
    time_file => 60
  }
}
```

Comment: When the hash uses the `=>` notation, then it is not a JSON hash but a Ruby hash. Because you only shared a config file and not your code, it is unclear what exactly your problem is and what it might be causing it.

Comment: @spickermann there is no code right now, I have kinesis where i am inserting json data, here is sample data in which i am getting arrow notation
0,,,"{""lat""=>""19.075975"", ""region_code""=>""16"", ""long""=>""72.877377"",

Comment: You need to include a complete, minimal, and reproducible example of your data, your code, and your expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the mutate filter in Logstash to replace "arrow (=>)" with "colon (:)".

```
input {
  kinesis {
    application_name => "logstash"
    kinesis_stream_name => "events"
    type => "kinesis"
    region => "us-east-1"
    profile => "default"
    metrics => "cloudwatch"
    codec => "json"
  }
}

filter {
  # Use the mutate filter to replace "arrow (=>)" with "colon (:)"
  mutate {
    gsub => [
      "message", "=>", ":"
    ]
  }

  grok {
    match => { "[data][ti]" => "%{YEAR:event_year}-%{MONTHNUM2:event_month}-%{MONTHDAY:event_day}" }
  }
}

output {
  s3 {
    bucket => "test-logstash"
    region => "us-east-1"
    prefix => "%{event_year}/%{event_month}/%{event_day}/%{[data][brandid]}/%{[data][event_name]}"
    encoding => "none"
    codec => csv {
      separator => "␁"
    }
    size_file => 200000000
    time_file => 60
  }
}
```

In the filter section, the mutate filter is used to perform a global substitution (gsub) to replace "arrow (=>)" with "colon (:)". This should ensure that your JSON data is correctly processed as expected.

Make sure to adjust the field name (message) in the mutate filter if your JSON data is located in a different field.

Answer (score 0):

When writing your Hash to the CSV file, convert it to JSON using `as_json` or a JSON string using `to_json`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working solution of mine, I used ruby filter to stringify json attributes

```
filter {
    grok {
      match => { "[data][ti]" => "%{YEAR:event_year}-%{MONTHNUM2:event_month}-%{MONTHDAY:event_day}" }
   }

    ruby {
      code => "
        require 'json'
        begin
          event.set('[data][attributes1]', event.get('[data][attributes1]').to_json)
          event.set('[data][attributes2]', event.get('[data][attributes]').to_json)
        rescue Exception => e
          @logger.error('Ruby exception occurred: #{e}')
          raise 'error'
        end
      "
    }
}
```